# Change background image on all scenes iOS 7

Tags: ios7, uiimage, storyboard

The storyboard looks like the image below. In each scene I had to drag an UIImage object from the object library, size it to fit between the nav and tab bars then set its image to that baige blur with the attributes inspecter.

I'm curious, is there a way to do it in one go to all scenes from the appdelegate.m file? thanks

[image: StoryBoard Scenes - Add Background Images in one shot?]

Comment: I guess NO option for this..You have to set from all.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your AppDelegate:

```
    [self.window setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"whatever.jpg"]]];
```